# Most efficient way to empty an array

Tags: php

I have an array containing several keys, values, objects etc.. I need to empty that array but I'd like to do it in the most efficient manner.

The best I can come up with is:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val) unset($array[$key]);
```

But I don't like the idea of having to loop through the array to just empty it.. surely there's a nice slick/clever way of doing this without wasting memory creating a new array?

Note: I'm not sure myself if it does cost extra memory in creating the array as new again. If it doesn't then $array = new array(); would be a fine way of 'emptying' it.

Comment: Why dont you do like unset($array), instead looping it.

Comment: unset deletes the actual array - I don't want to do that.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this is not obvious. The things not covered by manuals because they are so "obvious" tend to ruin your day /week.

Comment: try using array_keys(), which will return u all keys. and your original array will remain intact.

Comment: The array keys method sounds good.

Comment: "Micro optimization is the root of all evil" :)

Comment: You could be onto something there KingCrunch. This is probably the point at which one stops using PHP and starts using C or something a bit more heavyweight.

Comment: Wait... you need to keep keys intact? but clean the value ?

Comment: @JohnHunt You know: This quote comes from Donald Knuth (the original is about "Premature optimization [..]") and is valid for any language ;) The point is, that memory management is something, that (depending on the language (not C ;))) you should never have to take care of, but the engine. :)

Comment: @Khez - No I wanted to remove both keys and values but not the array itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$array = array();
```

Comment: Isn't this a waste of memory in that you're creating a new array?

Comment: Agree with John Hunt, it will allocate another memory location to it.

Comment: I actually went to a talk on how the zend engine stores things in memory.. $array = array(); is the best way.. it basically frees up what $array contained without creating a new zval (most efficient) also what what @KingCrunch said was bang on.. PHP is smarter than you and handles memory management in a very clever/efficient manner so you don't have to think too much about managing memory :)

Answer (score 2):

It highly depends on what you mean.

To empty the current reference you can always do

```
$array = array();
```

To completely remove the current instance from the scope

```
unset($array);
```

Unfortunately both of these cases don't necessarily mean the memory associated with each element is released.

PHP works with something called "references" for your variables. Your variables are actually labels or references pointing to data, not the actual container for data.
The PHP [garbage collector](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php) can offer more insight on this subject.

Now take a look at this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php#example-387), taken from the docs:

```
$a = "new string";
$c = $b = $a;
xdebug_debug_zval( 'a' );# a: (refcount=3, is_ref=0)='new string'
unset( $b, $c );
xdebug_debug_zval( 'a' );# a: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)='new string'
```

This unfortunately applies to all your variables. Including arrays. Cleaning up the memory associated with the array is a whole different subject I'm afraid.

---

I've noticed a longer discussion in the comments regarding using unset() on each individual key.

This feels like extremely bad practice. Consider the following code:

```
class A{
    function __construct($name){$this->name=$name;}
    function __destruct(){echo $this->name;}
}

$a=array();
$b=array();
$c=array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    $a[]=new A('a');
    $b[]=new A('b');
    $c[]=new A('c');
}

unset($a);
$b=array();

echo PHP_EOL.'done'.PHP_EOL;
```

This will output:

```
aaaaabbbbb
done
ccccc
```

When the reference to a particular data structure reaches 0, it is cleaned from memory.
Both `=array()` and `unset` will do the same thing.

Now if you don't actually need `array()` you can use `null` :

```
$array=null;
```

This keeps the label in memory, but removes the reference it held to any particular data.

Comment: And yes, I wanted to empty it.. not remove it entirely.

Comment: Updated by answer based on the comments I've noticed. I'm uncertain what it is you are trying to achieve or why you believe you need to unset each individual key to clean memory.

Comment: @JohnHunt Regarding arrays: "empty it" and "replace it with an empty array" is the same. You should not treat arrays as objects, but as values, because they arent objects. Therefore Khez answer is slightly misleading, because carrying an array around as reference (for whatever reason, there is no valid) usually leads to unexpected and hard to track behaviours

Comment: @KingCrunch I disagree. The only reason I'm using objects in the second example is due to easier debugging and understanding garbage collection events (via `__destruct`). You can see in my first code example this is valid for any data structure. References are everywhere in PHP.

Comment: @Khez Guess, I get you wrong. However, the refcount reacts on`$a = $b` in the first example because of copy-on-write takes effect, which means, they are only references as long as you don't try to change one of both. Must make some experiments before, but I guess this is the case ;)

Comment: Yes I'm starting to think the best way to settle this is to write some tests. Then again in my case I'm still with KingCrunch.. I probably don't need these micro optimisations just yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple:

```
$array = array();
```

$array will be existing and type of array (but empty), and your data can be garbaged later from memory.

Comment: The problem is if your script is getting hit 100s/1000s of times a second then the memory is still used up until that script finishes executing. There will be a lot of stuff in my array - objects etc. so it's fairly important it gets cleaned up when I want.

Comment: so maybe force garbage collect with `gc_collect_cycles()` ? Or just do not create new objects but rewrite new data to old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well... why not: `$array = array();` ?

Answer (score 0):

As Suresh Kamrushi pointed out, I could use array_keys:

```
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) unset($array[$key]);
```

This is probably the nicest solution for now.. but I'm sure someone will come up with something better soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// $array is your original array

$array = array_combine( array_keys( $array ), array_fill( 0, count($array), 0 ) );
```

The above will blank your array keeping the keys intact.

Hope this helps.